# How can I play a movie and add a text overlay with DirectX in C#

Tags: c#

How can I play a movie and add a text overlay with DirectX in C#, please specify some references, because I am new in this area.

Answer (score 0):

the specific part of DirectX tused for video playback is called DirectShow, you need a reference on how to use DirectShow from c#, a staring point could be this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/directshowmediaplayer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series2/tut18.php for some source code on displaying text on a DirectX surface...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a form that initializes a Direct3D, creates a couple of triangle vertices, and displays the video on them. Because I have no understanding of vertices it isn't quite lined up correctly, but it successfully loads the video and renders it as a texture onto the triangles.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{   
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Device _device;
    private Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font font;
    private Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback.Video _video;

    CustomVertex.PositionTextured[] vertices;

    public void Init()
    {
        PresentParameters present_params = new PresentParameters();
        present_params.Windowed = true;
        present_params.SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard;

        _device = new Device(0, DeviceType.Hardware, this, CreateFlags.SoftwareVertexProcessing, present_params);

        font = new Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D.Font(_device, 20, 0, FontWeight.Bold, 0, false, CharacterSet.Default, Precision.Default, FontQuality.Default, PitchAndFamily.DefaultPitch, "Arial");

        _video = new Video("clock.avi");
        _video.TextureReadyToRender += new TextureRenderEventHandler(_video_TextureReadyToRender);
        _video.RenderToTexture(_device);

        vertices = new CustomVertex.PositionTextured[6];
        vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 0f);
        vertices[0].Tu = 0;
        vertices[0].Tv = 1;
        vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(-1f, -1f, 0f);
        vertices[1].Tu = 1;
        vertices[1].Tv = 1;
        vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(1f, -1f, 0f);
        vertices[2].Tu = 0;
        vertices[2].Tv = 0;
        vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(-1.1f, -0.99f, 0f);
        vertices[3].Tu = 1;
        vertices[3].Tv = 0;
        vertices[4].Position = new Vector3(0.99f, 1.1f, 0f);
        vertices[4].Tu = 0;
        vertices[4].Tv = 0;
        vertices[5].Position = new Vector3(-1.1f, 1.1f, 0f);
        vertices[5].Tu = 1;
        vertices[5].Tv = 1;
    }
    void _video_TextureReadyToRender(object sender, TextureRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        _device.BeginScene();
        _device.SetTexture(0, e.Texture);
        _device.VertexFormat = CustomVertex.PositionTextured.Format;
        _device.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 2, vertices);

        font.DrawText(null, "test overlay", 5, 5, Color.Red);

        _device.EndScene();
        _device.Present();
    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        _device.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.Blue, 0.0F, 0);

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _video.Play();
    }
}
```

You need to put your scene drawing code within the `TextureReadyToRender` event, otherwise your video will never show up.

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need, but the video simply does not show. I don't want the video to be shown inside a triangle, I just want to show text on top of the video. Would you mind showing me how?